# Why do I lose CSS when floating a div?

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to create a responsive layout. Everything works great until I float a div to the left. I then lose:

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Site Title</h1>
    <nav>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
    </nav>

    <h2>hello world</h2>
    </div>

</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 980px;
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow: auto;
}

nav {
    background-color: #222;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 10px 0;
}


nav a { color: #F9F9F9; display: block; float:left;  padding: 10px;  }
nav a:visited { color: #f9f9f9; }
nav a:hover { text-decoration: none; background: #27B3CF; }
nav a:active { position: relative; top: 0; }
```

**Working but I want to float it left**
http://jsfiddle.net/rktjam2k/4/

**Problem when nav a is floated left:**
http://jsfiddle.net/rktjam2k/3/

Comment: Have you considered using a ul instead?

Comment: ul being un-ordered lists?

Comment: yeah, they are generally better practice for what you are trying to achieve. By using `display:inline` you will get the horizontal effect and it will allow you to style appropriately.

Comment: Why on Earth would that be better practice?

Comment: @Gary - there's a long discussion about it at http://css-tricks.com/navigation-in-lists-to-be-or-not-to-be/ . But it's irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Gary, do you actually think that using floats for a navigation is _better_ practice?

Answer (score 4):

You must clear the floats.

For example, add

```css
nav {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 980px;
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow: auto;
}
nav {
  background-color: #222;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
nav a {
  color: #F9F9F9;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
}
nav a:visited {
  color: #f9f9f9;
}
nav a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #27B3CF;
}
nav a:active {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
}
a {
  outline: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}
h1 {
  font-family: 'Droid Serif', serif;
  line-height: 75px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 90px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Site Title</h1>
  <nav>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
  </nav>
  <h2>hello world</h2>
</div>
```

Or

```css
nav:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 980px;
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow: auto;
}
nav {
  background-color: #222;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
nav:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
nav a {
  color: #F9F9F9;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
}
nav a:visited {
  color: #f9f9f9;
}
nav a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #27B3CF;
}
nav a:active {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
}
a {
  outline: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}
h1 {
  font-family: 'Droid Serif', serif;
  line-height: 75px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 90px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Site Title</h1>
  <nav>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
  </nav>
  <h2>hello world</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Works great. Would you be so kind and give an explanation as to why this works and why you must clear floats? Thanks again.

Comment: when you give overflow:hidden to floated element's parent it will clear floats..

you can use clear:both aswell on your h2 tag instead of overflow

Comment: @JonathanSaich If you don't clear the floats, the following block element will be placed at the right of the floated elements. To avoid that, you can make the container wrap the floats with `overflow: hidden` (or anything but `visible`), or you can add `clear: both` (or `left`) to the following element.

Answer (score 0):

because you dont use < in CSS! This should make it work properly

```
nav < a { color: #F9F9F9; display: block; float:left;  padding: 10px;  }
nav < a:visited { color: #f9f9f9; }
```